LVP over Linoleum?
Can I put LVP directly over lino in my basement? The lino is in pretty good shape other than lifting at some corners (pictured in photos). I was thinking I could cut out the lino where it’s lifting and use concrete patch to level the floor in those areas - yay or nay? And should I use underlayment, or will the lino act as underlayment?
Here are some pics of the current situation
And this is the vinyl plank we want to install

Planks care more about a floors flatness than what the floor is.  Linoleum is quite thin/within the depth the planks can cover easy, so unless there is a decent dip, might not need any building up.  Stairnose might be nice with a dark colour, make it an accent.

You're asking two questions here. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. One question per post. Also, the literature that ships with your product holds the true answer to your question. That's always the first place to start with any product. Answers you get here will be generally applicable. You want specifics so you don't void your warranty.

Yes, you can install LVP over the linoleum.
You can use additional underlayment that is rated for LVP and use an LVP product that approves use with an underlayment.  ( They must work as a system.)
You don't need to cut out the areas that are lifted if they are slight. If you do cut them out you don't need to patch with anything if it is just an inch or so from the wall. The LVP will not react with such a little difference in height, coupled with minimal foot traffic that close to the wall. Baseboards help when reinstalled as well. (Remember to leave 1/4 " gap at the end of each board to the wall.)
The only issue I see is with the product that you plan to use.   4.2mm is very thin.
The thinner the product the more likely that you will have those problems that people worry about, like seam separation and unevenness.  I recommend a product that is minimal 5.5 mm. Less than that and the solid core is too thin to perform well.  Do yourself a favor and look for a product that is thicker. That product may also have the preformed stair nose. (you know the metal stair nose must be removed.)
